# Shared Memory program behaving weirdly

Tags: c, unix, ipc, shared-memory

I've written the following code to make 2 processes chat using shared memory. But I'm facing some weird problems.

Let's say you send a message from process A, it gets displayed on process B's stdout and you can keep sending messages from process A without any problem. But as soon as you try to send a message from process B, everything stops working. No message is displayed on A. If you now try to send something from A, even that doesn't work. Even worse, if I start a new process, the second process generates a lot of garbage output at first, and then becomes dysfunctional - no further output gets displayed. I don't really understand what's going on.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

struct message {
    int senderid;
    char msg[100];
};
struct message_q {
    int write_ptr;
    int writing;
    struct message msgbuffer[100];
} *pmsgq;

key_t key;
int shmid;

int lastRead = -1;
void handleRead() {
    while(1) {
        while(lastRead+1 != pmsgq->write_ptr) {
            // don't display our own messages
            if(pmsgq->msgbuffer[1+lastRead].senderid != getppid())
                printf("Remote: %s\n",pmsgq->msgbuffer[++lastRead].msg);
        }
    }
}

void handleWrite() {
    char msg[100];
    while(1) {
        scanf("%s", msg);
        while(pmsgq->writing) 
            ;
        pmsgq->writing = 1;
        strcpy(pmsgq->msgbuffer[pmsgq->write_ptr].msg, msg);
        pmsgq->msgbuffer[pmsgq->write_ptr].senderid = getpid();
        pmsgq->write_ptr++;
        pmsgq->writing = 0;
    }
}

int main() {
    key = ftok("shared_mem_chat.c",'b');
    shmid = shmget(key, sizeof(struct message_q), IPC_CREAT | 0666);
    pmsgq = (struct message_q*) shmat(shmid, NULL, 0);
    pmsgq->write_ptr = 0;
    pmsgq->writing = 0;

    if(fork() == 0) {
        handleRead();
    }
    else {
        handleWrite();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The reason to split Read and Write in two separate processes is to enable "live" chatting - otherwise scanf will block the execution till something is entered.

And I've also added a simple locking mechanism - I know that the write code here isn't really atomic, but I added it just for, let's say, simulating locking.

Comment: 1) add the code to check the returned values from `shmget()`, `shmat()` to assure the operations were successful.  2)  add the code to check the returned value from `fork()` for when it fails. 3) when done with the shared memory, pass the pointer to `shmdt()`.  4) the main process must call `wait()` or `waitpid()` before exiting.  The child process must not call `shmdt()`

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to make lastRead a volatile.  It seems to me like one process is caching that value and not getting the update from the other process.  Just declare it like this

```
volatile int lastRead = -1;
```

Comment: I just found the bug. The problem was with the condition in the handleRead() method. The lastRead variable doesn't get incremented if the condition isn't satisfied and hence the reader gets stuck in an infinite loop doing nothing. Thanks for looking into my problem.